# simplest ways to keep a local database

Tags: c#, database, local

I'm fairly new to c# and I was wondering what different options there are for keeping a database on the user's PC.

It's basically for saving favorites and being able to add a note on each favorite, and then i'd be able to show a list with all favorites and their note. 
But I honestly have no clue how to even do that, I've worked with mySQL but I can't do that here.

Thanks

Edit: The program is comparable to an internet browser but for a specific website, so it won't be that big of a database

Comment: Is this for a web application?  More information about the application would be helpful. Thx.

Comment: How big is your data? do you really need a DB?

Comment: Why can't you work with MySQL? Knowing that reason might also quickly eliminate some other similar options that people might otherwise suggest.

Comment: @L.B Even for small datasets, it's probably simpler to use EF and an embedded database than rolling your own persistence. (This assuming you know how to use those tools.)

Comment: @MarkByers Why would you want to use MySQL? MySQL is decent on servers, but I'd avoid distributing it with my desktop application. I'd prefer sqlite or postgre.

Comment: For this problem I'd probably use a xml or json config file instead of a db. Then deserialize the file when starting the app, and save it when the favourites change.

Comment: @Inerdial, Serializing some classes to disk could also solve the problem which would be much simpler than EF.  It depends on the needs

Comment: @L.B Unless you need to do incremental updates to "live" state. That's why I said the size of the dataset doesn't matter, the use case does.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I wasn't going to suggest using MySQL. I want to know his reason for excluding it as that might provide useful information into his specific thought processes and/or requirements as that could influence my suggestion.

Comment: @Inerdial, would you really need a DB for `saving favorites and being able to add a note on each favorite`? As a user, I wouldn't want to install a DB just for this case.

Comment: @L.B Need? No. I'd still use them though. (Emphasis on the "I", meaning as someone who's already familiar with embedded databases and ORM.)

Comment: @Inerdial, I know you are the only one `who's already familiar with embedded databases and ORM`

Comment: @L.B Please stop putting words in my mouth.

Comment: Well it indeed doesn't have to be a database, I just don't know how all of this works and I've worked with mySQL database before. I suppose I could just as well use a text file then

Comment: @L.B "As a user, I wouldn't want to install a DB just for this case." – that's also why I said *embedded* database.

Comment: @Inerdial, I wouldn't also make an external dependency just for this case :). Is this really very hard to accept that a universally correct solution doesn't exist.

Comment: @L.B I never said or implied that embedded DB + ORM is a universally correct solution. Just that it is by no means inherently more complex to implement than dumping an object graph into a file; and that you were wrong about the user having to install a dependency. If you really need to win at the internet so badly that you need to misrepresent what I'm saying, just go ahead and have a celebratory cookie. Nobody will know.

Comment: @Inerdial, It seems that you start to get into absurd topics. I am sorry that I wouldn't know this `serialization` issue would hurt you so personally. OK if this helps stop you bugging me, I will use an embedded DB whenever I need to save a user info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need a database.  For something that simple, a file would do.

If you want a database, I'd have a look at [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx), or SQLite as Mike suggests.

Answer (score 5):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a simple and common way to bundle a local relational database with an application. It has ADO.NET (C# database bindings) at [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).

However, if you're just storing a simple set of tuples, wouldn't a comma-separated list saved as a regular text file on disk work just fine?

Comment: I would recommend SQLite over a CSV file, since as the application adds features over time a database is much more scalable than a CSV format.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET, the path least annoying will likely be [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) or [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/)

Answer (score 2):

There are many such databases - the Microsoft one is [SQL CE](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx).